# SQL *PLUS subquery CHECK needed

Tags: sqlplus

Show the universities (by name) with the 5 highest final scores.  Also show the meet name.  To do this, you’ll need to write a statement that (1) includes a ROWNUM clause and (2) joins the university, univ2meet, and meet tables through a `SELECT` statement within the `FROM` clause.

Above is what is I'm asked to write.

This is what I have so far..

```
SELECT universityName, meetName

FROM (SELECT *

FROM university a, univ2meet b, meet c

WHERE a.universityID = b.universityID, c.meetID = b.meetID

ORDER BY univFinalScore DESC)

WHERE ROWNUM <= 5;
```

// university entity is parent of univ2meet

// meet entity is parent of univ2meet

Comment: So I'm glad to see at least what you've got. Now...which part of the query were you asking about?

Comment: I'm asking about the subquery, is it correct?
As a totall SELECT statement, is it correct?

Comment: You'd be best served stating that in your question, as a friendly heads-up.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that it will run. As long as it runs, it meets the requirements you listed.